# DROOLS: It's easy to make conditions based on >, < or =, but how can we make condition for human readable rules?

Tags: java, drools, business-rules

I have started exploring DROOLS execution engine, so I have not much idea about DROOLS. I have found it very easy while creating a rule for following business rule:

```
 "Event is large event if number of audience is greater than 1000"
```

Drools rule will be:

```
 rule "Large Event"
    when
        event: Event(audience>= 1000 )
    then
        event.setEventType("largeEvent");
  end
```

Where Event is a class and audience , eventType are the attributes of the class.
But I am getting it difficult while creating a rule, which have conditions other than >, <, ==. Consider the following example:

```
 Bank verifies customer if customer submits document.
```

If anyone deal with such type of rules, please help me. Is there any example or document available to learn such type of example.

Comment: How is the fact that a customer has submitted a (certain) document registered in your customer data? How would you write the condition "customer has submitted document" in Java? Show us this code, and we can show you the rule.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I have stuck here only, for such type of facts how can I make conditions in java as well as in Drools. Above mentioned example is a plan English text that we have to convert it in drools. But I am completely blank that how can I convert it in condition?

Comment: You cannot convert "if customer submits document" to code unless you have a lot more. Apart from the issue which document is meant (birth certificate? driver's licence? ...) you need to have a data model where you store information about a customer and documents and other stuff. Do you have any idea about programming and data processing?

Comment: I think I have not convey the question correctly.  Simple thing I want to ask is: How can we write drools rule from a plan English text. As far as I go through Drools documentation, It says that we have create POJO classes with their getter and setters. In this case suppose I have two classes Bank and Customer.   Can I make drools condition as follows based of above mentioned text :                       when  customer.isSubmitDocument== true then bank.setIsVerifiedCustomer(true)

Answer (score 1):

This is trivial. The only complication was you strange roundabout way of asking a simple question.

```
rule "Customer has submitted a document"
when
    $b: Bank()
    Customer( submitDocument )
then
    $b.setVerifiedCustomer( true );
end
```

Note: Although this corresponds to your comment (Why don't you edit your question?) it seems rather silly: why would one set a property of the *bank* if there is just one customer with a submitted document?

Comment: Thanks @laune. It will help me a lot. Can I ask in detail about Customer (submitDocument ) ?  What it will do ? Does it call constructor of class Customer ? Is submitDocument is an attribute of class customer ? Again its a trivial doubt , but it will help me understand it in better way. Thanks once again.

Comment: I was paraphrasing your 'customer.isSubmitDocument'. Typically you would have a field `boolean submitDocument`, a getter isSubmitDocument` and a setter 'setSubmitDocument'. That's the convention. Using the field name alone is enough with Drools DRL to call the getter and return a boolean.

Comment: Thanks laune. I have created drl rule for following condition          / *rule 'bank verifies customer' It is obligatory that bank verifies customer if   customer is individual && document is eaadhaar */
rule "bank verifies customer"
 when 
   $cusObj: Customer1();
   $iObj: Individual();
   $doc: Document();
   $eaadhar: EAAdhar();
  eval( $iObj instanceof Customer1)
  eval ($eaadhar instanceof Document )
   
 then
  System.out.println(bank.isVerifyCustomer());
  bank.setVerifyCustomer(true);
  
end    Here Individual inherits Customer1 and EAAdhar inherits Document.

Comment: Please refer attached link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46804312/how-to-pass-multiple-facts-for-some-sets-of-rules-in-drools